# Update selenium server

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I'm using selenium server (standalone jar), launching it from java code. I'm trying to 
update it from

```
selenium.rc.version=2.0 
selenium.rc.revision=a2
```

to

```
selenium.rc.version=2.0 
selenium.rc.revision=rc2
```

code:

```
RemoteControlConfiguration rcc = new RemoteControlConfiguration(); 
rcc.setPort(port); 
try { 
    server = new SeleniumServer(false, rcc); 
    server.boot(); 
} catch (Exception e){ 
     //whatever 
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities.opera()Lorg/openqa/ selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities; 
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions $1.<init> (DefaultDriverSessions.java:47) 
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.<clinit>(DefaultDri verSessions.java: 42) 
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.createWebDriverRemoteContext(Sele niumServer.java: 310) 
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.assembleHandlers(SeleniumServer.java: 296) 
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.createJettyServer(SeleniumServer. java: 258) 
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.<init>(SeleniumServer.java: 231)
```

I tried downloading webdriver-opera-v0.4.3.jar and adding it to build 
path but error persists. Same code works in a2

Any guesses?

Comment: Can you publish your import statements?

Comment: import org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteControlConfiguration;
import org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer;

Comment: Does your build path contain any other Seleniumserver version? I tried to run your code in my machine and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue when I tried to update new version of selenium server. I deleted the existing selenium server and replaced with selenium-server-standalone-2.13.0.

The solution is to update "selenium-java" jar file to match your new Selenium-Server.

1. Download "selenium-server-2.13.0" and "selenium-java-2.13.0" zip files from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list
2. unzip them to a location. Make sure to have "selenium-server-2.13.0", "selenium-java-2.13.0" and all the dependent jars in eclipse build path or you build file.